# Two column grid without using row class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, freemarker

I am generating HTML pages at run time with the help of freemarker. This poses some limitation on the HTML generation part.
Currently to show input fields in two grid column, I need to define each row and place my fields in it.
**Current HTML**

```
<body class="container">
    <div class="section-outline">
        <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
        <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">First Name:</label><input type="text" required/></div>
        <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Middle Initial:</label><input type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid show-grid">
        <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Last Name:</label><input type="text" required/></div>
        <div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Social Security Number:</label><input type="text"/></div>
        </div>
```

Can I get same result without putting `span6` divs in a row? I want same result with something like:

```
<div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">First Name:</label><input type="text" required/></div>
<div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Middle Initial:</label><input type="text" /></div>
<div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Last Name:</label><input type="text" required/></div>
<div class="span6 form-inline"><label class="pocLabel">Social Security Number:</label><input type="text"/></div>
```

**Here**

```
.show-grid [class*="span"] {
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline;
}
label.pocLabel {
    width: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.section-outline {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/wa2YQ/

```
.span6.form-inline {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
}
.span6.form-inline label {
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

or
http://jsfiddle.net/wa2YQ/1/

```
.span6.form-inline {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.span6.form-inline label {
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

or else ?

Comment: Both gave me same result. You were right on with the `<div>`s but I want `<label>` and `<input>` fields of a div inline.

Comment: okay, i just do not really understand what you expect from you label/input ? should they be side by side , or on top of each other ( http://jsfiddle.net/wa2YQ/2/ )?

Comment: Label/input side by side but their divs in two-column grid.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wa2YQ/5/ ... http://jsfiddle.net/wa2YQ/6/ ? actually, i would need a drawing to understand :)

Comment: ? here label/input are on top of each other. what's not working ?

Comment: One of your property is getting overridden by `bootstrap.css`

Comment: All the fields are on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :nth-child, but this is only supported in recent browsers

```
.show-grid .span:odd {
   /* Your css for left floating */
}

.show-grid .span:even {
   /* Your css for right floating */
}
```

If you need to support older browsers you can change the order of the fields and float them left next to each other.

Comment: I tried using `nth-child(even)` and `(odd)` but '<div>'s were not inline propery.

Answer (score 0):

if you want do do that without placing span6 inside row then you first need to get rid of row-fluid you are using in the main container div. Just use row there and and apply offset to to move the required div to the right.like this pen http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/wfFnG

First Name:
      Middle Initial:

Last Name:
         Social Security Number: